# For active page link how can i make data-alt-src image taht use as hover show as active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For active page link, how can I make `data-alt-src` image that use as hover show as active:

```
<div class="navigation"><ul><li><a href="#" class="swap_image"><img class="icons" data-alt-src="images/menu-i1-h.png" src="images/menu-i1.png" alt=""></a></li></ul></div>
```

Here is the javascript

```
 var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
    $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', newSource);
}

$(function () {
    $('.swap_image img').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
```

So, if use active than data-alt-src will show by default. How can it be done like this? http://screencast.com/t/ydcER96G9L9

```
Using something like this: <div class="navigation"><ul><li class="active"><a href="#" class="swap_image"><img class="icons" data-alt-src="images/menu-i1-h.png" src="images/menu-i1.png" alt=""></a></li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your code here and corrected your typo in the html:

https://jsfiddle.net/jskd2der/

Everything works just fine now.

I just changed this:

```
<div class="navigation">`<ul>`<li><a href="#" class="swap_image"><img class="icons" data-alt-src="images/menu-i1-h.png" src="images/menu-i1.png" alt=""></a></li></ul></div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="navigation"><ul><li><a href="#" class="swap_image"><img class="icons" data-alt-src="images/menu-i1-h.png" src="images/menu-i1.png" alt=""></a></li></ul></div>
```

Now what you mean when you say "show as active", what do you want to show? Try please to be some more specifc.

Comment: Everything is possible, but for this to work I need to see how you gather the  data when you load the page.

Comment: For normal page  no active  class: http://screencast.com/t/DDs9clM5

for active  class: http://screencast.com/t/b2czrrJuhgrI

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it when the page loads you can do:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //get user data somwere, if user is active
    if(data = 'active'){
        //show the active image (the yellow one)
    }else{
        // show the grey image
    }
})
```